# Messed up Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to get this:

```
<select name="id" onchange="window.location=('viewforum.php?id='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <optgroup label="Test category">
        <option value="2">New forum</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">New forum</option>
        <option value="4">New forum</option>
        <option value="5">New forum</option>
        <option value="1">Test forum</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

from this:

```
<div>
    <label>
        <span>Jump to<br></span>
        <select name="id" onchange="window.location=('viewforum.php?id='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
            <optgroup label="Test category">
                <option value="2">New forum</option>
                <option value="3" selected="selected">New forum</option>
                <option value="4">New forum</option>
                <option value="5">New forum</option>
                <option value="1">Test forum</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value=" Go " accesskey="g">
    </label>
</div>
```

And my Regex which is this:

```
qJumpHTML.replace(/.*\<select|\<\/select*/gi,'');
```

is giving me this:

```
<div>
    <label>
        <span>Jump to<br></span>
            name="id" onchange="window.location=('viewforum.php?id='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
        <optgroup label="Test category">
            <option value="2">New forum</option>
            <option value="3" selected="selected">New forum</option>
            <option value="4">New forum</option>
            <option value="5">New forum</option>
            <option value="1">Test forum</option>
        </optgroup>
        >
        <input type="submit" value=" Go " accesskey="g">
    </label>
</div>
```

So, what do I need to change in my Regex to allow me to get the string I want? from said string?

Comment: Can you simplify the example? It is hard to understand what is your problem with so much code...

Comment: There's only one line of actual code. All that HTML is just a string. The line to look at is the Regex. I'm basically trying to get all of the string between the <select> tags.

Comment: Simplifying the example is still good advice, for your programming in general, when things aren't working out at first

Comment: Would it make more sense to manifest the string into DOM and retrieve the <select> element? Afterwards, if you still needed it in string format, you can convert it. In other words, is there a specific reason why you *have* to use Regex? Or can I provide you with a different method of obtaining what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = qJumpHTML;
var result = d.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].outerHTML;
```

[THE PONY HE COMES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and you have absolutely NO excuse since you're working in JavaScript!

Comment: THANK YOU. Beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 1):

`/(<select[^>]*>.*?</select>)/gs`

Comment: How well is `</select>` going to parse?

Comment: It's fine, see the "Grabbing HTML Tags" example here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Comment: I think `/s` flag (dot matches all) would be needed here.  So flags would be `/gs`

Comment: @MElliott, yes! Thank you :) I always forget which flags I need and where to put the darn things...

Comment: @Vasili Syrakis, Yes your pattern matches and would work per the question.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
qJumpHTML.replace(/.*(<select.*?<\/select>).*/gi,'$1');
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, but that just gave me the full string.

Comment: This works if you use `'$1'` instead of `'\1'`. I think we're generally encouraged to use `$1` instead of `\1` for replace strings (the regex itself is another matter). Although I'm surprised Palpatim's answer failed in this particular way.